# how to pass Image data uri from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, pdf

I have a webpage which displays a chart. I had to generate a pdf of this chart. So I wrote this code to capture the chart as an image and put inside the pdf. I used html2canvas for this which generated a data uri for the image. Now I am stuck with this uri in javascript. The pdf code is a php script which needs this uri. How do I do this ?
The chart.php generates the chart and using html2canvas stores the image datatauri into localstorage.

```
CHART.PHP
    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
      (function() {
         window.onload = function(){
             html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart'), {
                  "onrendered": function(canvas) {
                       var img = new Image();
                       img.onload = function() {
                           img.onload = null;
                           console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                           window.localStorage.setItem("imgURL", canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                       };
                       img.onerror = function() {
                           img.onerror = null;
                           if(window.console.log) {
                               window.console.log("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                           } else {
                               //alert("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                           }
                       };
                       img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                   }
                });
             };
         })();
    //]]>
    </script>    
    <body>
       <a href="pdfGen.php" id="download" >Report</a>
    </body>
```

This is the php script which generates the pdf using fpdf library

```
pdfGen.php
    <?php
        /*$pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();

        //over here I want to add the image from the chart.php page whose data url is now in the localstorage.
        ..more code to generate report
        $pdf->output();*/
     ?>
```

How do i send the such a big uri to this php script ? Trying an ajax wont work as I need to redirect to this php page. Also sending the uri along in the url wont work either as the url becomes too large and goes beyond its capacity.

Comment: insert url into a hidden variable in a form and get it in php page using post or get..

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: madhusoodan prabhu answer should give you what you need mate.

Answer (score 1):

In your **script** :

```
<script>
document.getElementById('imageURL').value=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
</script>
```

create a form in ur body with a report button and an hidden field for URL :

```
<body>
<form action="pdfGen.php" id="download" method="post">
<iput type="hidden" id="imageURL" name="imageURL"/>
<input type="submit" value="Report" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

In your **php** page - **pdfGen.php**

```
<?php
$imageURL = $_REQUEST['imageURL'];
?>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

```
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
  (function() {
     window.onload = function(){
         html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart'), {
              "onrendered": function(canvas) {
                   var img = new Image();
                   img.onload = function() {
                       img.onload = null;
                       console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                       document.getElementById('imageURL').value=this.src;
                   };
                   img.onerror = function() {
                       img.onerror = null;
                       if(window.console.log) {
                           window.console.log("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                       } else {
                           //alert("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
                       }
                   };
                   img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
               }
            });
         };
     })();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: not really.  I get the error of undefined index imgURL

Comment: try using $_POST["imageURL"]

Comment: print the post variables in ur php  page using print_r($_POST); and check if ur getting post variables correctly

Comment: one more wthing document.getElementById('imageURL')=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
should be document.getElementById('imageURL').value=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

Comment: put document.getElementById('imageURL').value=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  in your html2canvas onrendered function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also creaate file from base64 and send it to server, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31592969/5138198) (works from ie10 and all modern browsers)